# how to calculate time correctly

Tags: python, opencv, video

im having problems doing this:
I have a video, I want to read it and draw circles on it in realtime. I have three lists with x,y coordinates for the circles, and times in second.

```
x = ['20' , '30' , '40', '50','60' , '70' , '80', '90','100' , '110' ]
y = ['20' , '30' , '40', '50','60' , '70' , '80', '90','100' , '110' ]
times = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]#Seconds
```

I want to draw on the video each coordinates associate with each second, so

```
One second, Draw a circle with 20(x) and 20(y)
Two second, Draw a circle with 30(x) and 30(y)
Three second, Draw a circle with 40(x) and 40(y)...
```

and so on.

I have tried something but im really bad

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
import time

a = ['20' , '30' , '40', '50','60' , '70' , '80', '90','100' , '110' ]
b = ['20' , '30' , '40', '50','60' , '70' , '80', '90','100' , '110' ]
time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]#Seconds

#ceate a capture object-------------------------------------------------------------------

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(r'C:/Users/aless/Documents/GitHub/Tobii-Glasses-Thesis/video/scenevideo5.mp4')

i=0

while(cap.isOpened()):
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   time_passed = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))
   if time_passed % (time[i]*1000) and i<=(len(time)-1):
      print(time_passed)
      # draw circles
     
      cv2.circle(frame, (int(a[i]),int(b[i])), 10, (255, 0, 0), -1)
      cv2.imshow('test', frame)  # draw
      i+=1
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After drawed first circle it don't draw the other. Can someone help? :C

EDIT 1:
I tried in this way, but it gives me error

*error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'*

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
import time

a = ['20' , '30' , '40', '50','60' , '70' , '80', '90','100' , '110' ]
b = ['20' , '30' , '40', '50','60' , '70' , '80', '90','100' , '110' ]
times = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]#Seconds

#ceate a capture object-------------------------------------------------------------------

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(r'C:/Users/aless/Documents/GitHub/Tobii-Glasses-Thesis/video/scenevideo5.mp4')
count = 0
success = True
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
i=0

while(cap.isOpened()):
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   time_passed = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))
   for x,y,t in zip(a,b,times):
      if count%(t*fps) == 0 :
        
         # draw circles
         cv2.circle(frame, (int(x),int(x)), 10, (255, 0, 0), -1)
         cv2.imshow('test', frame)  # draw
      count+=1  
   
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: try without `if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break`

Comment: see this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924896/python-opencv-dont-put-circle-on-the-video

Comment: @GhostOps See the edit, don't work

Comment: **always** check for errors. it's always the same with videocapture. `assert cap.isOpened()` (once!) and in the loop: `if not ret: break` right after each cap.read

Comment: next issue: milliseconds aren't seconds. there's a factor of 1000 between them. just use `int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) / 1000)`, which will be good enough for your code. then use that value as an index into your list. *remove* the `count%(t*fps) == 0`, it makes no sense

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I dont understand the part "assert cap.isOpened() (once!) " what i have to fix? And i also don't understand how use int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) / 1000). Can you show me step by step if you can :C Im really new with this sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues:

- `count += 1` should be outside the `for` loop.
- The condition `count % (t*fps) == 0` is incorrect.
  You have probably meant it to be `if (count - (t*fps)) == 0`
  In case `fps` is not an integer, we may also check: `if abs(count - (t*fps)) <= 0.001`
  In case `fps` is an integer we can simply check:

  ```
   if count == (t*fps)
  ```

---

**Debugging the code:**

Instead of working on some arbitrary video file, it's simpler to debug the code using synthetic video file.

The following code creates a synthetic video, with running frame counter:

```
vid_filename = 'synthetic_video.mp4'
width, height, fps, n_frames = 320, 240, 25, 300

synthetic_out = cv2.VideoWriter(vid_filename, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (width, height))

for i in range(n_frames):
    img = np.full((height, width, 3), 60, np.uint8)
    cv2.putText(img, str(i+1), (width//2-40*len(str(i+1)), height//2+40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 4, (30, 255, 30), 8)  # Green number
    synthetic_out.write(img)

synthetic_out.release()
```

---

For testing, add `cv2.waitKey(1000)` after `cv2.imshow('test', frame)`.
Waiting a full second allows us to see if the circle is drawn on the correct frame.

---

Place a breakpoint, start debugging and place relevant variables in the watch window.

Example (using [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE):
[image]

It also helps executing the code step by step...

---

Complete code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os.path

# Build synthetic video for testing (320x240 at 25fps and 300 frames)
################################################################################
vid_filename = 'synthetic_video.mp4'

if not os.path.isfile(vid_filename):  # Create the file only once (if not exists).
    width, height, fps, n_frames = 320, 240, 25, 300

    synthetic_out = cv2.VideoWriter(vid_filename, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (width, height))

    for i in range(n_frames):
        img = np.full((height, width, 3), 60, np.uint8)
        cv2.putText(img, str(i+1), (width//2-40*len(str(i+1)), height//2+40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 4, (30, 255, 30), 8)  # Green number
        synthetic_out.write(img)

    synthetic_out.release()
################################################################################


a = ['20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100', '110']
b = ['20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100', '110']
times = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  # Seconds

# create a capture object-------------------------------------------------------------------

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_filename)
count = 1  # Start counting from 1 - assume first frame is 1 and not zero (draw a circle on frames 25, 50, 75 and not 26, 51, 76...)
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
i = 0

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret is False:
        break  # Break loop in case ret is false (should be false after the last frame)

    for x, y, t in zip(a, b, times):
        if count == (t*fps):
            # draw circles
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), 10, (255, 0, 0), -1)
            cv2.imshow('test', frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1000)

    count += 1
   
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Output samples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, im having problem using list of time like this.

`[0.5, 2.0, 4.6, 6.2, 6.6, 6.8, 7.3, 7.8, 8.2, 9.1, 9.3, 10.2, 10.6, 11.0, 12.2, 16.3, 16.5, 17.0, 17.9, 19.1, 19.6, 19.9, 20.5, 20.9, 21.7, 22.7, 23.9, 26.2, 27.2, 27.5, 28.9, 29.9, 30.2, 31.3, 31.7, 33.3, 34.9, 35.2, 37.5, 37.9, 38.6, 38.9, 39.4, 40.2, 41.5, 41.8]`

I have changed if as you said `if abs(count - (t*fps)) <= 0.001`
No error it just don't even open the video, i think is if problem (?)

Comment: And There is a way to let dot stay on the next frame??

Comment: The way "letting the dot stay" is keep drawing the circle on every frame (drawing it at the same place until it changes position). `abs(count - (t*fps)) <= 0.001` is just an example, you can try: `abs(count - t*fps) <= 1`. Please use the debugger, and try solving the problem by yourself.

Comment: Is possible draw on every frame also all the previus dot drawed?

Comment: Yes, just keep drawing in the last `x`, `y` position found by the for loop. Modify the for loop to something like: `for x0, y0, t in zip(a, b, times): if abs(count - t*fps) <= 0.5: x, y = int(x0), int(y0)` (save `x`, `y`). And draw in every cycle `cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 10, (255, 0, 0), -1)`. Also use `imshow` and `waitKey` every cycle. Think how to solve the case of the first frames.